# Add multiple organizations in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have installed CRM 2011 server. when i try to add a second organization to the CRM server through CRM Deployment Manager it gives a warning message "To Create a new Organization, the wizard must remove the current organization ''. after the wizard completes you will no longer have access to this organization."

[image]

couldn't find anything useful through google also. please let me know if anyone has an insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the license key used is for workgroup server which limits you to 1 organisation and 5 users. To fix this change the license key to a server edition.

See this for server editions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699677(v=crm.5).aspx